# How to color row dynamically in GridMvc 3.0.0

Tags: css, asp.net, grid.mvc

I am using the GridMvc 3.0.0 in ASP.net MVC5 project. I am using it to display a list of cars that can be usable or not usable. So, i want to change the row depending on the car status (usable or not) in my search i find that i can use fonction "SetRowCssClasses". It work but not correctly. the css is apply on same row like ramdomly, i think.

That is my code:

---

@Html.Grid(Model).SetRowCssClasses(v => v.Disponible.Equals(false) ? "cssClassRed" : string.Empty).Columns(columns =>

{columns.Add(v => v.immatriculaton_vehicule).Titled("Numero d'immatriculation ").Filterable(true);

columns.Add(v => v.Disponible).Titled("Disponibilité");

---

My css is like this:

```
.cssClassRed{
background-color: red;
```

}

am i missing someting???
Need your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the result so i post it.

SetRowCssClasses(e => e.propriety.Equals("some value") ? "success" : o.Libelle_propriety.Equals("other value") ? "info" : string.Empty)

success and info show the color of the line (green and blue)